# Can not get document DB when using seesion

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, transactions, aws-documentdb

I'm trying to create a transaction with my document DB version 4.0.0.
I was able to open a session but when I try to get the database information I get this error messages:
**session.getDatabase is not a function**

```
    let session = await beginTransaction('matan');
    let assetSessionObject = session.getDatabase('matan').getCollection('test');
```

I'm using mongodb: 3.6.6 driver from, So maybe the problem is that there is no driver 4.0.0 yet?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe `getSiblingDB('matan')` instead of `getDatabase('matan')`?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to upgrade to a MongoDB driver that is compatible with 4.0. Even though sessions came out in MongoDB 3.6, if you want to use transactions with Amazon DocumentDB or MongoDB, you're going to have to upgrade to 4.0 compatible drivers anyways as that's major version when transactions was introduced.